# How can i write excel columns into one column in text file?

Tags: python

I have an excel sheet and have huge data in many columns and I need to print those columns to follow each other in one column in a text file .. I searched a lot for a tool to do this but couldn't find and tried to take it manually but I'm stuck in the data. Can this be done by python?

i have data like this in excel

```
1760    -67.4144    -51.5741
1761    -70.0035    -52.6686
1762    -82.4125    -33.0582
1763    -88.4259    -35.5613
1764    -63.6835    -38.474
1765    -90.6215    -43.0932
1766    -65.9159    -38.9343
1767    -76.7137    -42.3622
1768    -94.9792    -31.1532
1769    -71.3852    -46.629
1770    -65.8548    -47.4222
```

and need to write them in text file like this

```
1760
1761
1762
1763
1764
1765
1766
1767
1768
1769
1770
-67.4144
-70.0035
-82.4125
-88.4259
-63.6835
-90.6215
-65.9159
-76.7137
-94.9792
-71.3852
-65.8548
-51.5741
-52.6686
-33.0582
-35.5613
-38.474
-43.0932
-38.9343
-42.3622
-31.1532
-46.629
-47.4222
```

Comment: Are you trying to export this data? Pandas can read [MS Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html) if that's the case. Also under the tab Data, you can usually manipulate column data into another format within excel.

Comment: So you are trying to get column name in a text file from a excel file?

Comment: @mah111 i have 1800 columns and need to print them in one column in text file .. do you mean like group from data tab ?

Comment: @rish_hyun i need to take all data in the columns from excel to write them in one column in text file

Comment: Sorry, it still seems unclear to me, can you provide an example

Comment: @rish_hyun please see the edit post

Comment: @mah111 I tried it but the rows in excel don't enough for 1800 columns and rows .. i need 3 million row at least

Comment: I have included an answer, let me know if I am missing something

Comment: "Can this be done by python?" Yes. Just about anything you can imagine that a computer can do can be done in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run this command in terminal

```
pip install pandas
pip install openpyxl
pip install xlrd
```

Then run this in python

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx')

my_file = open('my_file.txt','w')
for data in df.columns:
    my_file.write(df[data].to_string(index=False)+'\n')

my_file.close()
```

To remove empty Nan values from seies, use `dropna`

```
my_file.write(df[data].dropna().to_string(index=False)+'\n')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping .. i tried it not but I got most of the lines   NaN .. i think because there is empty cells among some columns .. can I ignore it ?

Comment: Sorry buddy! I didn't see your message. In case you want to drop NaN values, I have updated my answer. One thing to also note here is column names is *excluded* to be print in this program, if you also want to print that I will update my answer